# Setting of spinner default text?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-spinner

I have one spinner in my project where values comes from database and displays in spinner. But i want to set one default value to spinner as "Select Item" and the values which comes from database needs to be add next to it. The following code which i am using is...

code:

```
  ArrayAdapter<String> adp=new ArrayAdapter<String> (this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,arraylist);
  spinner.setAdapter(adp);
```

Here i am adding the values which i get from database as arraylist to spinner & values are displaying directly. But i want to display one default value to be displayed as "Select Item". How to set that. can anyone please help me with this..? I want as per the below image...

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add element at `0th index using .add(0,"Select Item");`

**MORE CLEAR**

```
arraylist.add(0,"Select Item"); //Add element at 0th index

ArrayAdapter<String> adp=new ArrayAdapter<String> (this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,arraylist);
spinner.setAdapter(adp);
```

Comment: And how to fill radio button? Radio button is like question's image.

Answer (score 1):

What about appending your arraylist with "select item"?:

```
arraylist.add(0, "select item");
```

Or create new arraylist for display purpose that contain "select item" in first index.

Comment: And how to fill radio button? Radio button is like question's image.

Answer (score 1):

I have one option if you don't want to change your Arraylist.

Put a TextView make its background Image as of a Spinner. On Click of it Open a AlertDialog which will contain the list of values, so set the Adapter to it.

Then add onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) to get the selected value and set it to you textview (the fake spinner).

Hope it helps !

Comment: Ok. No problem. Enjoy Happy coding

Answer (score 0):

You can change it to a Text View and use this:

```
android:style="@android:style/Widget.DeviceDefault.Light.Spinner"
```

and then define the `android:text` property.